# Excel VBA: Converting Range Object to Array

Tags: vba, excel

Background: The code you will view below is for a guest list. When executed, it will ask for a list of first names, a list of last names, a list of email addresses, a point value, and an event name. Then, the program enters the event name on the first row of the first empty column. Then, the if loop checks each name that it was supplied to as a list against an existing list in a spreadsheet. If the first and last name are found, it adds the point value to the new event column for that row. If the name is not found, it adds the first and last name to a new row at the bottom, the email address, two formulas for totals, and then the point value within the new column. This is the intended scenario.

I first obtain a list of names with the following code

```
Dim fNameStringRange As Range

fNameStringRange = Application.InputBox("Select the list of first names.", "Obtain Range Object", Type:=8)
```

Then I convert it using the user function `RangeToArray`. The code for this is below:

```
Function RangeToArray(inputRange As Range) As Variant
Dim inputArray As Variant
inputArray = inputRange.Value

'operations on inputArray
'...'

RangeToArray = inputArray
End Function



Dim fNameString As Variant

fNameString = RangeToArray(fNameStringRange)
```

For some reason however, my code does not process this through as such. When I have it fill these names into my sheet, it doesn't fill in anything. Before, this would work just fine using a `InputBox` of `type:=2`. Any assistance is appreciated. My full VBA script is below:

```
Sub addEvent()


On Error Resume Next

Dim fNameStringRange As Range
Dim lNameStringRange As Range
Dim sEmailStringRange As Range
Dim fNameString As Variant
Dim lNameString As Variant
Dim sEmailString As Variant
Dim nPointVal As Integer
Dim sEventName As String
Dim n As Integer, r As Long, c As Range, d As Range, e As Range, p As Range, sE As Range
Dim fName As Range, lName As Range, sEmail As Range, z As Range
Dim lEvent As Integer
Set fName = ActiveSheet.Range("FirstName")
Set lName = ActiveSheet.Range("LastName")
Set sEmail = ActiveSheet.Range("eMailAddr")


fNameStringRange = Application.InputBox("Select the list of first names.", "Obtain Range Object", Type:=8)
lNameStringRange = Application.InputBox("Select the list of last names.", "Obtain Range Object", Type:=8)
sEmailStringRange = Application.InputBox("Select the list of email addresses.", "Obtain Range Object", Type:=8)
fNameString = RangeToArray(fNameStringRange)
lNameString = RangeToArray(lNameStringRange)
sEmailString = RangeToArray(sEmailStringRange)
nPointVal = InputBox("Please enter a point value for this event")
sEventName = InputBox("Please enter the name of the event.")

lEvent = NextEmptyColumn(Range("A1"))
Set sE = Range("A1").Offset(0, lEvent)
sE.Value = sEventName
' sEventPos = sE.Offset(0, lEvent)

If fNameString <> False And lNameString <> False Then

    For i = LBound(fNameString) To UBound(fNameString)

        fNameString(i) = Trim(fNameString(i)) ' Trim off leading and trailing whitespace.
        lNameString(i) = Trim(lNameString(i)) ' Trim off leading and trailing whitespace.

        Set c = fName.Find(fNameString(i), LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)
        Set d = lName.Find(lNameString(i), LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)

        If Not c Is Nothing And Not d Is Nothing Then

                Set p = c.Offset(0, lEvent)
                p.Value = nPointVal


        ElseIf c Is Nothing And d Is Nothing Or c Is Nothing And Not d Is Nothing _
         Or Not c Is Nothing And d Is Nothing Then

            Set c = fName.End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0)
            c.Value = fNameString(i)
            Set d = lName.End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0)
            d.Value = lNameString(i)
            Set e = sEmail.End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0)
            e.Value = sEmailString(i)
            Set p = fName.End(xlDown).Offset(0, lEvent)
            p.Value = nPointVal

            Dim s As Range ' Our summation range
            Set s = Range(c.Offset(0, 4), c.Offset(0, 4))
            Dim rD As Integer
            rD = Application.WorksheetFunction.RoundDown((s.Address / 250), 0)

            c.Offset(0, 3).Formula = "=((" & s.Address & "/250)-ROUNDDOWN((" & s.Address & "/250),0))*250"

            Set s = Range(c.Offset(0, 5), c.Offset(0, 42))
            c.Offset(0, 4).Formula = "=SUM(" & s.Address & ")"
            c.Offset(0, 5).Value = 0

        End If

    Next

End If

End Sub
```

Comment: It's not clear exactly what you're doing, and you haven't posted enough code for us to figure it out, so it's going to be difficult for you to get useful answers to your question.

Comment: Full code added and additional information provided.

Comment: have you tried debugging with breakpoints? Is your code passing the `If` tests where expected?

Comment: I'm not sure how to use breakpoints. I read about them, but I still don't understand how to use them.

Comment: Can you maybe explain a little what the code is intended to do? And what happens inside of the `RangeToArray` function?

Comment: I think it is because you are trying to get the object selected with the inputbox as a range. if you declare them as variants that should get past that. Then maybe join the arrays together from that point.

Comment: Try putting a .Address after your inputbox method. That should then act how you had it with the type:=2
- Type:=8).Address

Or as my previous comment you can directly create an array by changing the var type to variant.

Comment: You need to use `Set fNameStringRange = Application.InputBox( ... , Type:=8)`

Comment: @chrisneilsen I've done that and it still will not work as intended.

Comment: @CaptainGrumpy I have tried both methods that you suggested and they did not work.

Comment: @TimWilliams Explanation of code added.

Comment: Just tested with the lines fNameStringRange = Application.InputBox("Select first names.", Type:=8).Address
lNameStringRange = Application.InputBox("Select last names.", Type:=8).Address
sEmailStringRange = Application.InputBox("Select email addresses.", Type:=8).Address        and although I cant be certain it does exactly what you need it does write the selected range's address to a string variable which is the same as type:=2.

Comment: Likewise, if you directly allocate the selected range to a variant such as fNameString in your code you will get an array, do it for all three and it might save the need for your other called function/sub RangeToArray. You will end up with three one dimensional arrays which you might want to test for consistent length but other than that look to be ok for the iteration you are performing.

Comment: @CaptainGrumpy could you share with me your code that you got to work successfully? I feel that I'd be able to learn best what's going on by looking at a working product.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a few modifications as requested. Looks like the biggest issue was not so much the array but you weren't clear c and d which meant the test was not moving to the else condition.
I cant be sure of that cause I had to play with a few things, make assumptions and make data. But I hope this gets you on the right track now.

```
Sub addEvent()

On Error Resume Next

Dim fNameString As Variant
Dim lNameString As Variant
Dim sEmailString As Variant
Dim nPointVal As Integer
Dim sEventName As String
Dim n As Integer, r As Long, c As Range, d As Range, e As Range, p As Range, sE As Range
Dim fName As Range, lName As Range, sEmail As Range, z As Range
Dim lEvent As Integer
Set fName = ActiveSheet.Range("FirstName")
Set lName = ActiveSheet.Range("LastName")
Set sEmail = ActiveSheet.Range("eMailAddr")


fNameString = Application.InputBox("Select the list of first names.", "Obtain Range Object", Type:=8)
lNameString = Application.InputBox("Select the list of last names.", "Obtain Range Object", Type:=8)
sEmailString = Application.InputBox("Select the list of email addresses.", "Obtain Range Object", Type:=8)
nPointVal = InputBox("Please enter a point value for this event")
sEventName = InputBox("Please enter the name of the event.")

lEvent = NextEmptyColumn(Range("A1"))
Set sE = Range("A1").Offset(0, lEvent)
sE.Value = sEventName
' sEventPos = sE.Offset(0, lEvent)

If fNameString <> False And lNameString <> False Then

    For i = LBound(fNameString) To UBound(fNameString)
        'clear the range variables to ensure the tests are correctly applied
        'was previously retaining old value and not progressing to second condition
        Set c = Nothing: Set d = Nothing: Set p = Nothing

        fNameString(i, 1) = Trim(fNameString(i, 1)) ' Trim off leading and trailing whitespace.
        lNameString(1, 1) = Trim(lNameString(i, 1)) ' Trim off leading and trailing whitespace.
        Set c = fName.Find(fNameString(i, 1), LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)
        Set d = lName.Find(lNameString(i, 1), LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)

        If Not c Is Nothing And Not d Is Nothing Then
            Set p = c.Offset(0, lEvent)
            p.Value = nPointVal
        ElseIf c Is Nothing Or d Is Nothing Then
            Set c = fName.End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0)
            c.Value = fNameString(i, 1)
            Set d = lName.End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0)
            d.Value = lNameString(i, 1)
            Set e = sEmail.End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0)
            e.Value = sEmailString(i, 1)
            Set p = fName.End(xlDown).Offset(0, lEvent)
            p.Value = nPointVal

            Dim s As Range ' Our summation range
            Set s = Range(c.Offset(0, 4), c.Offset(0, 4))
            Dim rD As Integer
            rD = Application.WorksheetFunction.RoundDown((s.Address / 250), 0)
            c.Offset(0, 3).Formula = "=((" & s.Address & "/250)-ROUNDDOWN((" & s.Address & "/250),0))*250"
            Set s = Range(c.Offset(0, 5), c.Offset(0, 42))
            c.Offset(0, 4).Formula = "=SUM(" & s.Address & ")"
            c.Offset(0, 5).Value = 0
        End If
    Next
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Wow, I didn't even think about the variables c and d needing to clear every time it iterates through. Well, it works as intended now. Thanks a ton Captain Grumpy!!!